# How to remove the page loading spinning wheel of UIWebView

Tags: ios, uiwebview

When using the `UIWebView` to load a page, while the page is being downloaded and loaded, a spinning wheel is being shown. Now, if I hit the back button before the loading or downloading is finished, the spinning wheel is still visible.

Is there a way to fix it ?

Thanks.

Comment: Call stopanimating and remove from superview In the method hooked up to the button that triggers the back operation.

Comment: @CodaFi : How do I do that ? I have called stopLoading though...doesnt work...

Comment: worked with [webview stopLoading].. was calling in the wrong place !!

Comment: do you mean the network indicator on the status Bar ??

Answer (score 0):

Write the following code in webview **Delegate** method

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    [loadingSpinner  stopAnimating];    
    loadingSpinner.hidden=YES;
}
```